# Why can't I respond to this Google Groups thread?

Tags: google-groups

I'm in a group and I want to respond to someone, but I can't because the 'respond' arrow is greyed out.

**Any idea what I can do to respond?**

This is what I see:

[image: This is what I see]

Comment: Have you checked if the thread is locked?

Comment: @Alex How can I see if a thread is locked?